# Control mouse pointer with keyboard without a number pad

Tags: mouse

I have dell laptop which does not have a numberpad, only a set of numbers above the qwerty layout.

I want to be able to control the mouse cursor with my arrow keys.

I activated the mouse keys by going to "System Setting" -> "Universal Access" -> "Pointing and Clicking" and activate "Mouse Keys"

But still, I am unable to control the mouse cursor.

How do I get this going so I don't have to take my hands off the keyboard?

Comment: are you using gnome or unity.?

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't have a NumPad, I don't think there is a way to get the normal Accessibility "mousekeys" that you're looking for.

You can use **keynav** instead (as suggested by sum2000) although that is a rather different experience.

You can configure it as follows (in ~/.keynavrc) to use the normal **Arrowkeys**, if that
s what you want:

```
Left cut-left
Down cut-down
Up cut-up
Right cut-right
control+Left move-left
control+Down move-down
control+Up move-up
control+Right move-right
```

It's in the repositories for Ubuntu 11.10, so

```
sudo apt-get install keynav
```

should work.

Comment: This is working, however, the file .keynavrc is not present in my home folder (hidden files shown). I would really like to reconfigure it for the arrow keys.

Comment: Then just add the file yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you have to hold the *Fn* button while you press the similarly coloured keys (not the arrow keys). the implementation is the same as on windows. e.g. up, down, left, right is 8,K, u, 0.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, i would suggest the normal way of doing it,Here it is,

It can help out partially . System -> Settings -> Assistive Technologies; then Keyboard Accessibility, under "Mouse Buttons"

Also using Shortcuts may help you too.

another way is using `ctrl-shift-numlock` that is supposed to be the key combo that will let you move the cursor with the keyboard, you can control the mouse from keyboard. Keys / and * on the numpad select left mouse click and right mouse click respectively. Mouse click is done by 5 on the numpad.

But as you are saying, you need something more ,then

here: http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/keynav/. And here is a demo of [keynav](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/keynav/keynav.html) in action

It is tested on Ubuntu 10.10 and it works fine. You have to install `libxdo-dev` before it would build (make), but then it ran fine. Note there's no 'make install' target, so just copy the keynav binary it builds to someplace in your path (~/bin, /opt/bin, etc).

Doesn't work awesome with dual monitors.Edit: NM. Split at least once, than use Shift+[hjkl] to move the divider around. That can jump you to the other screen.