# There is no keynavrc file for keynav in the home folder

Tags: mouse, keys, navigation

I recently installed keynav from the software center.

As per [this question](http://code.google.com/p/semicomplete/source/browse/keynav/keynavrc?r=2556&spec=svn2556), I wanted to change the configuration of keynav so that I could use the arrow keys instead of using a mouse to navigate the mouse cursor.

However, keynav did not place the ~/.keynavrc file into my home directory (I have hidden files shown). Is anyone here familiar with this program, and how can I reconfigure the keynav keys?

Answer (score 2):

This question was solved by the OP:

> You should find a sample `.keynavrc` already installed on your local system at `/usr/share/doc/keynav/keynavrc`
>
> Alternatively, you can find one online at:
>
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jordansissel/keynav/master/examples/keynavrc.jordan
>
> Copy the text. Open Gedit and paste the text. Save it as .keynavrc in
>   your home directory (don't forget the " . " before the name
>
> You can edit it to use the arrow keys as per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88948/control-mouse-pointer-with-keyboard-without-a-number-pad) answered by
>   hugoheden. logout and login
>
> It also helps to put keynav in your startup apps